# Geolocation doesn't work when building via phonegap build

Tags: build, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap project with geolocation. 
When I build it via the site phonegap build, it doesn't work on my phone or tablet (samsung). Always a time-out on the device.
When I build it via the CLI and install it on my phone via cable, then the geolocation works.

Do I need to change some setting to make it work via phonegap build?

Answer (score 0):

For phonegap-build, place this tag in your config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

Additionally, be sure to include this in your head:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></head>
```

After that, the API calls are the same.

*Note 1: do not attempt to actually put a phonegap.js file in your directory structure.

*Note 2: I have been hearing that some devices are having issues with GPS API's. If I find the SO post again I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks, but I have created the phonegap project via the Command Line Interface, and have added the plugin for geolocation also via CLI. So the feature-element is already in the config. Also the js-file is in the index.html by default.